# Space of labelled complex from

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

The following is taken from Munkres Algebraic Topology book

[image]

I am trying to determine which space (projective plane, mobius strip, Klein bottle, etc) this complex is but to no avail. I know it would be a projective plane $RP^2$ if there were lines connecting $a$ to $g$ and connecting $k$ to $a$. But without the lines, I don't know what complex it is. I am guessing its a sphere since its euler characterstic is 2. Any help appreciated.